# How can I improve and shorten this block of code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This function takes a string of DNA such as 'GTCA' and returns an array containing correctly matched DNA pairs.

```
function pairDNA(dna) {

  const pairs = []

  for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i ++) {

    if (dna[i] === "C" | dna[i] === "c") {
      pairs.push("CG");
    } else if (dna[i] === "G"| dna[i] === "g") {
      pairs.push("GC");
    } else if (dna[i] === "T"| dna[i] === "t") {
    pairs.push("TA");
    } else if (dna[i] === "A"| dna[i] === "a") {
      pairs.push("AT");
    }
  }

return pairs;
}
```

This is correct. However i'm trying to find a shorter, simpler way of writing it. Can anyone help me with what I should be using?

Comment: use easily this method dna[i].toLowerCase()

Comment: If your code works and you just want improvements, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think this code work as intended, `|`  doesn't do logical OR in Javascript like `||`

Comment: @mamounothman - That's true, but both will work in that code (`||` would be better, though).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can improve you code in following steps:

- When there are multiple if statements and all have same structure you probably need to use an object
- You need to check of both uppercase and lowercase. Just use `toLowerCase()` on input.
- You can `split` the string and `map()` it rather than creating an array `push()` values into it.

```js
function pairDNA(dna) {
  const obj = {
    c: 'CG',
    g: 'GC',
    t: 'TA',
    a: "AT"
  }
  return dna.split('').map(x => obj[x.toLowerCase()])

}
```

If the string could contain anything other the specific letters then you need to `filter()` the `undefined` values after `map`

```
return dna.split('').map(x => obj[x.toLowerCase()]).filter(x => x !== undefined)
```

Another better is mentioned by @RobG in the comments that we can remove the unwanted letters from string before looping through it.

```
return dna
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^cgta]/g,'')
        .split('')
        .map(x => obj[x])
```

Comment: If dna contains a non listed character you will have `undefined` values in your final array.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Added a fix for that case in my answer

Comment: Or you can pre–process the string with `dna.toLowerCase().replace(/[^cgta]/g,'')...`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Really liked that. I added it yo my answer.

Comment: I missed that it was a string. :-) FWIW, a more Unicode-friendly way of splitting strings into arrays now is `[...dna]`. It doesn't break up surrogate pairs. (Or `Array.from`, which is particularly useful if you're going to map: `Array.from(dna, mappingFunction)`.) (Not all that relevant here, I assume `dna` only contains `c`, `g`, `t`, and `a`.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably:

1. Use a `for-of` loop (or possibly mapping with possible filtering)
2. Use a lookup object or Map
3. Make the string lower or upper case when switching/looking up (but duplicated entries in the switch/lookup work too):

If you know that `dna` will only ever contain `c`/`C`, `g`/`G`, `t`/`T`/, or `a`/`A` (which, as I understand it, is true of DNA ;-) ), then you can use `Array.from` with its mapping feature with a lookup object/Map:

```
const table = {
    c: "CG",
    g: "GC",
    t: "TA",
    a: "AT"
};

function pairDNA(dna) {
  return Array.from(dna, entry => table[entry.toLowerCase()]);
}
```

I'm using `Array.from` because it will split the string on *code points*, not just code units (doesn't break up surrogate pairs) and has a mapping feature if you provide a mapping function. (Basically, `Array.from(str, mappingFunction)` is `[...str].map(mappingFunction)` but without the intermediate array.) Probably not all that relevant here given the content of your string, but can matter if your string may contain surrogate pairs.

Or with a `Map`:

```
const table = new Map([
  [c, "CG"],
  [g, "GC"],
  [t, "TA"],
  [a, "AT"]
]);

function pairDNA(dna) {
  return Array.from(dna, entry => table.get(entry.toLowerCase()));
}
```

If you can't make that assumption, add `.filter` to filter out the ones that didn't have a match:

```
function pairDNA(dna) {
  return Array.from(dna, entry => table.get(entry.toLowerCase())).filter(Boolean);
  // or if using an object: return dna.map(entry => table[entry.toLowerCase()]).filter(Boolean);
}
```

Or if you want to avoid creating the extra array the `filter` would create, stick with `for-of` (or even your `for`):

```
const table = {
    c: "CG",
    g: "GC",
    t: "TA",
    a: "AT"
};

function pairDNA(dna) {
  const pairs = [];

  for (const entry of dna) {
    const value = table[entry.toLowerCase()];
    if (value) {
      pairs.push(value);
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookup mapping to simplify the loop:

```
function pairDNA(dna) {

  const pairs = [], key = { G: "GC", C: "CG", A: "AT", T: "TA" };

  for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i ++)
    pairs.push(key[dna[i].toUpperCase()]);
  return pairs;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting I didn't think of doing it this way, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not shortened but definitely more maintainable.

```
function pairDNA(dna) {
  const map = {
    C: 'CG',
    c: 'CG',
    G: 'GC',
    g: 'GC',
    T: 'TA',
    t: 'TA',
    A: 'AT',
    a: 'AT',
  };

  return dna.split('').reduce((tmp, x) => {
    if (map[x]) {
      tmp.push(map[x]);
    }

    return tmp;
  }, []);
}
```

You could also do :

```
function pairDNA(dna) {
  const map = {
    c: 'CG',
    g: 'GC',
    t: 'TA',
    a: 'AT',
  };

  return dna.split('').reduce((tmp, x) => {
    if (map[x].toLowerCase()) {
      tmp.push(map[x]);
    }

    return tmp;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a `switch case` and a `forEach` funcion, like this:

```
function pairDNA(dna) {
  let pairs = [];

  dna.forEach( dnaValue => {
    switch (dnaValue.toLowerCase()) {
      case "c":
        pairs.push("CG");
        break;
      case "g":
        pairs.push("GC");
        break;
      case "t":
        pairs.push("TA");
        break;
      case "a":
        pairs.push("AT");
        break;
    }
  })

  return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lowercase the string which will allow you to remove the checking of capital string:

```
function pairDNA(dna) {
  dna = dna.toLowerCase();
  const pairs = []
  for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i ++) {
   if (dna[i]=== "c") {
     pairs.push("CG");
   } else if (dna[i]dna[i] === "g") {
     pairs.push("GC");
   } else if (dna[i] === "t") {
     pairs.push("TA");
   } else if (dna[i] === "a") {
     pairs.push("AT");
   }
 }

 return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const lookup = {
    c: "CG", 
    g: "GC", 
    t: "TA", 
    a: "AT"
};

function pairDNA(dna) {  

  const pairs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i ++) {
     pairs.push( lookup[dna[i].toLowerCase()] );
  }

  return pairs;

}
```